# Two points that are the same

Tags: function, geomedia

In my dataset there are two points that are identical in every way. I'm looking for a way to run some kind of query or functional attribute to make it such that there is only one point at this location.

Reason is that if I try and label this data set there will be two identical values and because they are 'Read-Only' types I cannot simply delete one of the labels.

I am working in GeoMedia Professional 2014

Comment: If you're working with something that's Read-Only, you can't "make it such that there is only one point", because that requires you to edit the file. Can you create an editable copy of the data?
If you must work in a read-only environment, can you use *Interactive Labels* to do this, then edit one of the two duplicate labels to be empty?

Comment: There is no way to write a functional attribute such that if you two attributes are the same only one point shows up?

Comment: I don't really see anything in the functional attribute commands that would identify a self-intersection. Even if you could identify attributes which were duplicates, how could you systematically select just one of them?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a spatial difference to remove the 2 points if they are exactly identical. Take the layer and do a spatial difference with itself